# Map a complex MVC ViewModel in knockout

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a MVC view which contains observables and observablearrays. What is the proper way to map?

My MVC ViewModel looks similar to this:

```
public class CategorysEditViewModel
{
    public Category Categorys { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Expert> candidates { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Expert> experts { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Policy { get; set; }
}

public class Expert
{
    public int ExpertID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExpertGUID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the cshtml file is strongly typed to the CategorysEditViewModel, you can serialize the view model object to JSON and then use the ko.mapping tool to map it to a knockout viewmodel.

Check out this post: [Best practice on passing Mvc Model to KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628938/best-practice-on-passing-mvc-model-to-knockoutjs/11636746#11636746)

Comment: I have followed your suggestion of using the ko.mapping tool. However now I have decided that I do not know how to reference these various observables within the HTML code. Here is a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/gilley81/Q4pRL/) link showing my current situation.