# Make backbone or knockout working with ORM

Tags: orm, backbone.js, knockout.js

For large project it's tedious to write models just for js side since we are using ORM on server side. Is there a good way to let backbone or knockout using server side ORM easily?

Comment: What do you mean ? make Backbone create models scafold-like copying the ones on the backend and creating JS objects ? I don't think so.

Comment: You can easily [create KO objects from your ORM objects in MVC][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628938/best-practice-on-passing-mvc-model-to-knockoutjs/11636746#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using node.js you can follow [this](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/) and have a single JS obj being used on both Frontend and Backend.

But with other langs I don't see how you can do that, you have to create your models and use rest requests to make changes to the Data.

Also I think that's the right way because almost always you don't need everything a Backend model has so you should architect you frontend like an application should be.

Comment: Thanks for the great link. It definitely bring some brilliant idea. However I still want to stick with .NET MVC platform. I am going to look at knockout mapping and see how far I can go from there. Best.