# Converting MVC Model to Knockout JS ViewModel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to convert my mvc model to knockout viewmodel here:

### Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    public List<MyList1> MyListOne{ get; set; }
    public List<MyList2> MyListTwo{ get; set; }  
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      MyModel myModel;

      var myServiceObject = myServiceManager.GetMyModelByUser(user);

      myModel = new MyModel
      {
        Id = myServiceObject.Id,
        .
        . 
        .
        .
      };

      return View(myModel);  
}
```

### View Model

```
var DynamicModelLoading = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

};
```

### Helper

```
public static string ToJson(this object obj)
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, serializerSettings);
        }
```

### View

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel;

    $(function () {
            var viewModel = new DynamicModelLoading(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));            
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
   });
</script>

<div class="f_name" data-bind="text: FirstName"></div>
<div class="f_name" data-bind="text: LastName"></div>
```

ToJson() returns data. But while binding it I am not getting any error and no data either. I am missing something here but not sure what it is.

---

### Answer

Here is the fix:

```
<div class="f_name" data-bind="text: firstName"></div>
<div class="f_name" data-bind="text: lastName"></div>
```

I was expecting the property name as same as my mvc model, but Json Serializer converts capitalized first letter to lower case by default.

Comment: hopefully something here will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628938/best-practice-on-passing-mvc-model-to-knockoutjs/11636746#11636746

Answer (score 1):

The issue must have something to do with the JSON result coming from @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));

Just to play around with the code a little, I created this fiddle which seems to be mapping the data correctly, and successfully binding it to the view: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lu8fdx2/

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var DynamicModelLoading = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
};

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new DynamicModelLoading({"testProperty":"testValue"});

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

This successfully binds the static JSON being passed in to "DynamicModelLoading()" to the HTML in the view. Here is the HTML:

```
<h4>Value For 'testProperty'</h4>
<span data-bind="text: testProperty"></span>
```

What happens when you log your viewModel to the console, just before calling 'applyBindings()'? Does it contain all of the properties from your original JSON object configured as observables (functions)? When I log the viewModel, this is what I get:

```
DynamicModelLoading {testProperty: function, __ko_mapping__: Object}
```

If the mapping is working successfully, you should get a similar result, but with all the properties from your object.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

var viewModel;

    $(function () {
            var viewModel = new DynamicModelLoading(JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'));  

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
   });